# image not appearing inside of div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navbar in my website and I want my logo to show next to my site name within the navigation bar, but it doesn't want to cooperate. In the code below is my html with the image inside of my nav bar.

Below is what my css looks like. I tried all of the different position types and I tried to set the navimage's margin and padding.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#navtitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
#navimage {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <p id="navtitle">Rainforest</p>
  <div class="navimage">
    <a>
      <img src='http://i.imgur.com/Eqbvkgb.png'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to put the image inside your paragraph.

`<p id="navtitle"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/Eqbvkgb.png'>Rainforest</p>`

Size the image as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `position: absolute` prevents the images from appearing as you want, try removing this and adding `display:block` so that the elements will appear next to each other. You'll probably want to change the css of your image to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Also the image is larger then 50 px so it automatically goes below the nav bar because it can't fit inside. Also, you have navimage title set to class in your html, but its written as an id in your css. ids are with # and class should be .navimage

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#navtitle {
float: left;
}
.navimage {
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div id="navtitle"><p>Rainforest</p></div>
  <div class="navimage">
    <a>
      <img src='http://i.imgur.com/Eqbvkgb.png'width="20" height="20">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Concept:**

Use of [float property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float).

**The Code:**

1. Use `float:left;`  for navbar and its elements.This will allow them to overlap each other.
2. Use [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to position them.

   *Note: I gave Id to the img itself. It is always easier to manipulate the image directly*

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float:left;
}
#navtitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: left;
}
#navimage {
  position: absolute;
  
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  float:left;
  
}
#logoimg{
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <p id="navtitle">Rainforest</p>
  <div class="navimage">
    <a>
      <img id="logoimg" src='http://i.imgur.com/Eqbvkgb.png'>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set an `absolute` positioning of the continer, so you should do in this way:

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;top:0;left:0;
}

#navtitle {
color: #FFF;
font-family: cursive;
font-size: 25px;
margin-left: 10px;
position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#navimage, img {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3upgedx/